# How to rewrite image/<text>-<imageID>-<text> to image/ID.jpg?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I used to have PHP websites and using url rewriting on picture to have SEO friendly urls,
On php I had links like 
`/image/blablablabla-1234-blablabla` 
rewriting to:
`/image/1234.jpg` 
by using a url rewrite rule on apache .htaccess file.

So I would like the structure `/image/<text>-ID-<text>` to return `/image/<id>.jpg` reguardless the text content.

Now I totally switched to ruby on rails and I would like to know what is the best way to do that on RoR? I am hosting websites on apache with passenger.

I guess the solution is in the rails route file but I can't figure out the appropriate way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you need to pass through the rails controller (for authentication, etc), you may:

A. Try the [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) plugin. You have this functionality out of the box.

[friendly_id guide](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html)

B. Add a before_filter in your controller (to parse any kind of URL in that form)

```
before_filter :rewrite_id

def rewrite_id
  if params[:id] && params[:id] =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]*-([0-9]*)-[a-zA-Z0-9]*/
    params[:id] = $1.to_i
  end
end
```

2. If this is just static data, it is better to be server directly by the frontend apache, so you should use the same technique as with php.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using already friendly id for articles with fixed comments.

In my situation I want to have a rewriting rule working with whatever the text 'blablabla' is.

Comment: Thank very much.
I think the B solution is the best way since each website might have different rules. I will give it a shot

Comment: The B method is working as expected. Thanks a lot.
I had it working on a video controller and using paths /video/show/<text>-1-<text> processed as /video/show/1

But with pictures the method is not working.
I have pictures stored in the path public/images/gallery/ of the rails application.
And by willing to rewrite the common /images/gallery/1.jpg by /images/gallery/first-1-image the method fails.
I created a images controller but the rewrite rule isn't working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The files in the /public folder are not served by Rails stack, but directly by Passenger. After all, it seems you will still need mod_rewrite :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The rewrite method in the controller will be useful to SEOize some stuffs. Merci Monsieur